# "Find a representation [using Mellin transform] of (,) as Gauss hypergeometric function in variable "

Tags: real-analysis, integration, integral-transforms, hypergeometric-functions

This is a follow-up to the first comment (by Nemo) to the posting [Compute the two-fold partial integral, where the three-fold full integral is known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322958/compute-the-two-fold-partial-integral-where-the-three-fold-full-integral-is-kno)   . (I also just asked this as a comment to that question itself--but suspected that it would remain rather obscure in that form.)

After a simplifying reparameterization (transforming $\beta$ into $\frac{b-1}{3}$) suggested by Matt F., the originally-posed problem took the form, 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{p=0}^1 \int_{q=0}^{1-p} (\mu p q (1-p-q))^b (\mu^2 q +p)^{-b-1} dq dp,
\end{equation} 
which has been employed since.

Answers to that question have, in fact, been posted by Martin Rubey and by me, but the possible one that was  apparently raised by Nemo--in terms of the original $\beta, p_{11,22}$ (rather than $b,p,q$) parameterization--has not so far been fully detailed. (In his comment, Nemo wrote "Did you try calculating Mellin transform of (,) wrt to  (the double integral over $p_{11,22}$ can be calculated using Dirichlet's Beta integral) and then recover (,) by inverse Mellin transform (which reduces to Barnes integral in this case? I did some calculations and if not mistaken this will lead to representation of (,) as Gauss hypergeometric function in variable ".)

Nemo also later commented "MartinRubey--my observation above about this function having a Gauss hypergeometric form is consistent with this logarithmic terms because 2 parameters of this hypergeometric function coincide", but this has not yet been expanded into an answer after a request of Rubey to do so.

So, to reiterate, I would like to explicitly know the presumed representation of (,) as Gauss hypergeometric function in variable , as this might be helpful in the pursuit of the program to construct "separability functions" presented in https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01973.

In fact, we have been able to find, as already detailed in the earlier answers,  a Gauss hypergeometric function expression for the linear (in $\log{\mu}$) term, 
\begin{equation}
w(b,\mu)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } 4^{-b} \mu^b \left(\mu^2-1\right)^{-2 b-1} \Gamma (b+1) \,
   _2F_1\left(-b,-b;1;\mu^2\right)}{\Gamma \left(b+\frac{3}{2}\right)},
\end{equation}
but not yet for the ``constant term'' $v(b,\mu)$ of the complete functional expression
\begin{equation}
v(b,\mu) + w(b,\mu) \log(\mu)=
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\Gamma \left(b+\frac{3}{2}\right)} \sqrt{\pi } 4^{-b} \mu^b \left(\mu^2-1\right)^{-2 b-1} \Gamma (b+1) \left(\log (\mu) \sum _{k=0}^b \mu ^{2 k} \binom{b}{k}^2-\left(\mu^2-1\right) \sum _{k=1}^b \mu^{2 k-2} \sum
   _{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{b}{i}^2 (\psi ^{(0)}(b-i+1)-\psi ^{(0)}(i+1))\right),
\end{equation}
where, 
\begin{equation}
\sum _{k=0}^b \mu ^{2 k} \binom{b}{k}^2=\, _2F_1\left(-b,-b;1;\mu ^2\right).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

In trying to implement the strategy of Nemo, I performed the integration of 
\begin{equation}
 \int_{p=0}^1 \int_{q=0}^{1-p} (\mu p q (1-p-q))^b (\mu^2 q +p)^{-b-1} dq dp,
\end{equation} 
for $b =1,\ldots,5$, then requested Mathematica to take the Mellin transform with respect to $\mu$ 
of the results.

For $b=1$, I obtained
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{3}
   \left(\mathcal{M}_\mu\left[\frac{\mu}{\left(\mu^2-1\right)^3}\right](s)+\mathcal{M}_\mu\left[\frac{\mu \log
   (\mu)}{\left(\mu^2-1\right)^3}\right](s)-\mathcal{M}_\mu\left[\frac{\mu^3}{\left(\mu^2-1\right)^
   3}\right](s)+\mathcal{M}_\mu\left[\frac{\mu^3 \log
   (\mu)}{\left(\mu^2-1\right)^3}\right](s)\right),
\end{equation}
for $b=2$,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{30} \left(3 \mathcal{M}_\mu\left[\frac{\mu^2}{\left(\mu^2-1\right)^5}\right](s)-3
   \mathcal{M}_\mu\left[\frac{\mu^6}{\left(\mu^2-1\right)^5}\right](s)-\frac{\pi  (s-2) s
   \left(e^{i \pi  s} \left(\pi  s^2-2 (\pi -2 i) s-4 i\right)-4 i (s-1)\right)}{32
   \left(-1+e^{i \pi  s}\right)^2}\right),
\end{equation}
for $b=3,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\pi  (s-3) (s-1) (s+1) \left(2 i (3 (s-2) s-1)+e^{i \pi  s} (6 i (s-2) s+\pi  (s-3)
   (s-1) (s+1)-2 i)\right)}{161280 \left(1+e^{i \pi  s}\right)^2} +
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-\frac {11} {420}
   \mathcal {M} _\mu   [\frac {\mu^9} {   (\mu^2 - 
        1   )^7}   ] (s) - \frac {9} {140}
   \mathcal {M} _\mu   [\frac {\mu^7} {   (\mu^2 - 
        1   )^7}   ] (s) + \frac {9} {140}
   \mathcal {M} _\mu   [\frac {\mu^5} {   (\mu^2 - 
        1   )^7}   ] (s) + \frac {11} {420}
   \mathcal {M} _\mu   [\frac {\mu^3} {   (\mu^2 - 1   )^7}   ] (s),
\end{equation}
....

So, since the required Mellin transforms do not all seem explicitly implementable, it appears to me that the Nemo goal of obtaining a (complete) representation of $f(\mu,b)$ (using the Matt. F. parameters) does not seem realizable.